# Exposure in the viewport is drasticly different than the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hdri, filmic-blender

Okay, I am used to slight differences between my view port and the test/final renders, but this is really odd. I have never had the exposure be this far off!

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Screenshot of the render and the viewport]

I am on 2.79a. using filmic. And, I think, just my usual settings. I have tried multiple hdrs and they all are wicked bright in this file.

[image: olor managment]

When I put the bullets into a new file and render with the same settings, the two match.

What did I bump with my elbow by accident?

Comment: Unfortunately you cropped your first image too tight. Do you have lights that are disabled for preview (eye icon in the outliner) and enabled for rendering (camera icon)? Is the Film exposure setting set to 1?

Comment: What do the nodes in the compositor look like?

Comment: Also, check those albedo values.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Thank you, @cegaton!

I had two area lights from testing the system previous to putting on the hdri that were turned off from preview (eye icon) but on in the render (camera icon) in the outliner.

Life is in the details!

[image: Whoops]